# Extracting multiple substrings from a string in shell script

Tags: regex, bash, shell

I have a file that contains the output of another command of the form:

```
aaaaaaaa   (paramA 12.4)   param2: 14,   some text   25.55
bbbbbb    (paramA 5.1)   param2: 121,   some text2    312.1
```

I want to pick the values `aaaaaaaa, 12.4, 14, 25.55` from first row and similarly `bbbbbb, 5.1, 121, 312.1` from row 2 and so on and dump them in a different format (may be csv).

I want to use regular expression in some command (sed, awk, grep etc) and assign the matched patters to say `$1`, `$2` etc so that I could dump them in the desired format.

What I am not clear is which command to learn for this. While searching around, sed, awk, grep seem to be capable of doing it but I could not quite get a readymade answer. I plan learn each of these commands but what do I start with to solve the problem at hand?

Comment: If your fields are separated by tabs, begin to learn awk.

Comment: @Casimir The default field separator in awk is one or more of any white space characters, so it's not necessary that the fields are separated by tabs.

Comment: @TomFenech: the idea is to explicitly use a tab character as FS to not see "some text" as two columns, instead of using the default FS.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte ah yes, I see what you mean. I guess another option with GNU awk would be to use FPAT to get the fields.

Comment: Thanks guys, I guess awk is what I should look into first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an input exactly like that, you can use

```
awk -F' +|)|,' -vOFS=", " '{print $1, $3, $6,$10}' file
```

which produces

```
aaaaaaaa, 12.4, 14, 25.55
bbbbbb, 5.1, 121, 312.1
```

However, that fails if you have more or less than two words in the last field, or if you have more then one word in the others.

Otherwise, you would have to look for numbers and distinguish it from text or you need to better characterize your input (fixed with, tab separated or based on some regex with sed).

Comment: Luckily, I know the number of words in the text field so I could use your script. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in `bash`:

```
# Not tested; regex may not be entirely correct.
regex='(.*) +\(paramA (.*)\) +params: (.*), +.* +(.*)'
while IFS= read -r line; do
    [[ $line =~ $regex ]] || continue
    # Captured groups are:
    # ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} - aaaaaaaa
    # ${BASH_REMATCH[2]} - 12.4
    # ${BASH_REMATCH[3]} - 14
    # ${BASH_REMATCH[4]} - 25.55
done < file.txt
```

However, it will be relatively slow. Using another tool like `awk` will probably be more efficient. It all depends, however, on what you actually want to do with the extracted text.